# Describe is not defined plus my config file does not run on protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, webstorm

I'm trying protractor for tests, but after install and config, i tried to run and the following error occurs:

```
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\andre.mendes\WebstormProjects\piloto\piloto.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Here's my code:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    it('should greet the named user', function() {
        browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

        element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('TheRoks');

        var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

        expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello TheRoks!');
    });})
```

So, i tried to run my config file, but nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

Start with a clean project and start playing with it. I recommend you to use the yeoman generator. https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-protractor

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. But turns out, is was a project structure issue.